# Why is this object $window in angular http promise object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following angular service:

```
app.factory( 'myService', function( $http ) 
{
    var service = 
    {
        someArray: [],
        updatePendingIds: function()
        {
            console.log( this );
            $http.get( "/get-stuff" ).
                then( function( response ) 
                {
                    console.log( this ); // someArray is not here!
                });
        }
    }
}
```

In the first console.log, before the angular promise object created "this" is the service object itself, as expected. That is, it will have a key "someArray".

But the second console log return this as the $window object. Two questions:

1. Why is this $window, and not the service object?
2. how do I pass the service object into the $http promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you created a new context when you created the function passed to the promise `then` method:

```
 then(  function( response ) // new function context
```

You'll need to bind that function to the object you need.

```
var handleResponse = function( response ) {
    console.log( this );
};

$http.get( "/get-stuff" ).then(handleResponse.bind(this));
```

Comment: works. Tried the following also, created the "handleResponse" function as a member of service, but still not bound. Had to actually call bind. e.g. "handleResponse: function() {...}" and then later "$http.get( url ).then( this.handleResponse.bind( this ));" Surprised the "bind( this )" required. Why?

Comment: @RafaelBaptista this is a common JavaScript misunderstanding, because Functions are first class objects.  Executing a function with scope e.g. `this.handleResponse()` is different from accessing an object property that contains a function e.g. `this.handleResponse`.  Accessing the property gives you the first class function that you are handing to the `.then` callback, but when the callback is executed, it no longer has scope.  (I hope that makes sense; the concept is hard to explain in a comment box. :) )

Comment: Actually, the term I'm looking for is "context" not scope.  This blog explains it well: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks that is helpful.